# Locomotive slowing to a crawl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have recently been building very small and simple apps using Locomotive 2.0.8. Until now it has been the ideal solution, but recently the application has slowed to absolute crawl. It takes literally 10 minutes to boot up, 5 minutes to add an existing or new project - and often these creations don't even work correctly. I can't imagine what I have done. I have tried uninstalling Locomotive, and clearing my directories. What could be causing this? Something to do with RubyGems? any other solutions besides Locomotive? Or how can I completely uninstall Loco, gems, and all my projects and essentially format my dev environment to start anew?

Comment: Note to quick-readers - this is **not** the [LocomotiveCMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com) for rails.

Answer (score 0):

Locomotive isn't really necessary anymore. You used to be a pain to get a decent ruby environment running on os x, but these days it's easy. Google for 'compiling ruby mac os x'

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to getting your rails apps running is to use [Pow](http://pow.cx/) to serve it and then use [Anvil](http://anvilformac.com/) to control Pow.

Bam!